# cpanel full account restoration without whm access

Tags: server, cpanel, restore, shared, account

Is there anyway we can restore a complete (or partial, but with the email settings intact) cpanel backup to a new account without the help of WHM?.

I have two reseller accounts - shared (hostgator). Have already downloaded the entire files (/ssl, /ftp, /mail, /public_html etc. ) using FTP from account 1.

Also created an account in 2nd hosting package with the same domain, username and password. Will it work if I upload all the files to the new server?.

Please note: I dont have root access also.

Comment: If you restore entire home directory data, it should restore your mail data and settings but you will have to make sure you have created all email accounts, forwarders etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can restore your account files through "Backup Wizard" feature. With this feature you can restore your partial backup zip file(s).

Please check it : https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Backup+Wizard#BackupWizard-PartialBackup